# Extension of 2D rotation matrix into 3D

Tags: vector-spaces, rotations

In 2D euclidean space, rotation matrix is a matrix that tilts every single vector in the 2D space, without changing the scale. For example following matrix rotates the space by 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

$$R_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Also, the tip of each unit vector is exactly the same distance from its original position, for example above, the tip of each unit vector moved by $\sqrt{2}$. This is parameterizable and we have a family of 2D rotation matrix given by

$$R_2(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\\end{bmatrix}$$

We can say that a rotation matrix is a linear transformation that moves all points on the surface of n-dimensional ball by the same amount.

This definition works for 1D, with the matrix $R_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-1\end{bmatrix}$ or $R_1(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}(-1)^{\theta}\end{bmatrix}$ in complex plane.

Is there a matrix $R_3$ in 3D that moves each point on the surface of the unit sphere by the same amount? Is there $R_n$ ?

Comment: Every rotation in three dimensions has an axis.

Comment: Can we prove that such a matrix does not exist for any dimension other than 1 and 2?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in rotations, or in any linear transformation that maps unit vectors to unit vectors. In the latter case, there’s $-I$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Any linear transformation as long as all the points on unit sphere are moved (but without moving the origin).

Answer (score 2):

In $\Bbb R^n$ with $n$ odd, each rotation (element of $SO(n)$) has $1$ as
an eigenvalue, so has a fixed point on the unit sphere.

If $n$ is even, consider the block matrix
$$\pmatrix{R&&&&\\&R&&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&R}$$
where $R$ is a $2\times2$ rotation matrix. This matrix shifts each point on the
unit sphere by the same distance.